# What should I do when I would like to move to a new lab because my current PI is abusive?

Tags: phd, advisor, management, abuse

I started to work in a Lab as a Researcher 4 months ago, with the prospect of being a PhD student. This Lab carries out research topics I am interested and passionate about but when I started there was only one PhD student working, so most of the research projects were stuck.

I am a very proactive and energetic person and I always try to give suggestions or ways to optimise experiments but my PI never listens (that's another issue, he does not like to optimise any new experiment, he thinks it is a waste of time and resources, and we actually end up wasting more resources in repeating experiments that are not working). He gets easily angry and just wants us to do exactly as he says (even though he usually forgets what he said).

I am not sure how to proceed. Should I just wait a little longer to see how things continue? should I enrol in a School before switching? or something else?

I feel depressed and no longer feel like the happy and passionate student anymore. I have a deep love for research and I don't want someone to interfere negatively on this.

Comment: This is a rant. You do not like your advisor and he does not like you (according to your version of the story). Then get out. Everything else is fluff. But "suggesting I should spend longer days" is not abuse. It is a suggestion. And "could give me a PhD project from the beginning to focus on" is not realistic. You are not just given a problem then you just do the work and instant PhD. Part of the PhD is actually defining the problem yourself and not strictly working on something that has been given by your advisor.

Comment: I understand your points, and appreciate it. I would actually like a PI that lets me work on something myself, rather than controlling every move I want to make and never listening to my ideas. And I can definitely spend longer days, if those days weren't spoiled by some of his harsh, sarcastic, or bitter comments. My real enquiry was not whether if I should "get out" or not. My real question is how to proceed on this transition. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: If your real question is how to proceed, why would say so much about your PI, not your future plans?

Answer (score 6):

A PI who is known to kick out some students, and graduate others after 10 (!!!!!) years, is not one you are likely well-placed with. I would certainly look into other labs. Leaving after such few months, when the period additionally was not officially grad school, might not be very hard. Just talk to other PIs, and, if possible, just profess greater interest in their topics as opposed to fleeing a colleague of theirs; it's better to leave on officially good terms, even if they weren't so good.

However, you *cannot* expect to always have a thesis topic served on a plate, and for sure not right when you start your Ph.D. - at least judging this from the U.S. perspective (if you are elsewhere, ignore the first half of this paragraph as all my experience is with the U.S. system). In many fields, finding your topic is an important part of writing your Ph.D. You might want to ask around in other groups or labs how things are there. Some advisers (I call them 'drawer advisers' - "What should I work on?", and the adviser opens a figurative drawer with topics they could not pursue yet) will do this for you; others won't. You also should listen to suggestions, and it's a bit early to expect your "optimizations" to be really, and always of use. If you genuinely dislike the PI's approach, you should see this as another reason to consider another lab (and try to be reasonably patient there).

The first version of this answer was wondering what exactly the adviser says or does which is upsetting. After your clarification, he seems unduly harsh, and I can see how that makes you feel depressed about your situation. I'm not convinced (yet) that this is because of sexism, but he sounds rude in ways that are simply not constructive for the close work necessary in a lab. Whatever the reason, it sounds bad, and I wouldn't take it. Some reasons (sexism for sure) could allow you to officially complain using your university's grievances procedures, but that's not a great start 4 months in.

Really, ask around, and see what else is out there. If nothing works at your current school, consider a gentler Ph.D. program approach with a period of coursework first, at another university, maybe in another country, a larger program size, and the almost inevitable student bonding which can be your support network.

Comment: As examples, he says things like "maybe I made a mistake in hiring you", or "as you are doing 70% of your work I should pay you 70% of your salary", or "where did your learn your science?". Even worse, as I come from a developing country he often loves to imply how grateful I should be to be in this much better european country, as if he is doing me a favor. But above all, he does not want to see all the hard work we do every day, even though it sometimes does not show results, and that his harsh attitude towards us every day is counterproductive for the lab (yes, he is around every day).

Comment: I feel my work is undervalued, and it seems he demands much more from this girl and me that he demands for the older PhD (who is a man). 

And thanks a lot for taking your time to answer.

Comment: And funny thing is that he usually only hires women. I think he feels he can mistreat us much easier than to male employees. 

I'm almost sure I want to switch to a new lab. What's stopping me is how easily he could find out I am doing it before I actually find one. I wonder how is the typical confidentiality when PIs are hiring new people.   Moving from the city is an option I would rather not take.

Comment: "I wonder how is the typical confidentiality when PIs are hiring new people". There is no such thing when a professor hires a student that used to work with another colleague. Before hiring, he should consult the previous supervisor to ask about the student's potential, work ethic, etc...

Comment: Being sarcastic is unpleasant, he can also be a demanding supervisor, but are there students who completed their PhD in good time? In any case, you feel mistreated, and this is perfectly fine as a reason to look for another supervisor. There are, however, some unclear statements from you: "he does not want to see all the hard work we do every day..." - unfortunately, hard work is necessary, but not sufficient for success; one can work hard in the wrong direction. Hard work alone won't get you a PhD - have you given him any results that look like they are on the road to success?

Comment: @CaptainEmacs: Your comment reminded me that my program had only about a 50% graduation rate (between those counseled out, and those leaving by choice); so yes, good point that one shouldn't look only at that tail end...10 years to graduation though hadn't happened in a long while, but it could even be a sign of patience on behalf of the adviser - it's a bit ambiguous w/o more details...

Comment: @CaptainEmacs I have given him some results, even I contributed in the last aspects of one paper (already accepted). But some weeks I haven't given results (I send him weekly reports every sunday), and for him is like I didn't work, even though I am just following his commands (I don't do experiments different from what he tells me to do), so in the end who's fault is that?. He doesn't let me contribute intellectually to my experiments, so I am just being a technician, basically.

Comment: Has he ever let you make decisions before? Can it be that he is concerned that you may not take the right decisions? I am not saying this is the case, I am just trying to find out what possibilities there are for such behaviour. There are extremely micromanaging people in science, utter perfectionists, but this is not everybody's cup of tea to have as a supervisor. These guys are only satisfied if one does things as they would do it, but one has to guess what that would be. Or else, surprise them in a positive way, but that is not trivial.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs I see what you say here, in the beginning I did some mistakes because of lack of guidance, but after some weeks I started to give some good results and he seemed pleased. Then at some point some experiments were not working (I was following carefully his advices, but in this case he just fixed some parameters for transfection without optimising in this cell line before), and he even though I insisted we should optimise first, he thinks it's a waste of resources, and the transfection never worked, and somehow he blames me, although not directly.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs during these months we haven't had a Postdoc, and I have heard that after many years he is back in the lab and doing experiments, so right now this seems like a particular situation in the lab. For the first time he is over-controlling his PhD students that closely, and although he is known to be a bad leader, he always had some Postdocs to cover up the PhD students.

Comment: @mermaid Well, then it seems there is a change in the situation as opposed to what you were used to. This can happen. Frankly, 4 months into the project is not long, and if you can change, it's probably a good idea. Otherwise, see yourself 4 years in this situation (which is 12x4 months), and, if it deteriorates, maybe even without a degree. So, if you are convinced it is not your problem, but the supervisor's, you really should reflect on whether you want to spend 12 times the time you already did in such an atmosphere.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs yes it seems it's getting worse. Some part of me even tells me he somehow wants me to leave, but he doesn't have the way to?. Seems that my behaviour is less submissive than he would like. Is this possible?

Comment: @mermaid Bullying is a well-known strategy to make people leave by letting it look like it was their decision. Be careful, however, to accuse anyone of bullying without a very clear array of evidence. In short, to answer your question, it's possible. Alternatively, he may resent, for instance, the way that you try to tell him how to run the experiments ("He never listens"). Style of communication matters, and students should take care not to come off as patronising (actually, this holds for everyone). Withouth knowing the other side, clearly, if you stay, there are unpleasant times ahead.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs This is valuable info. These days have been very useful to reflect and listen. Thank you very much for your insights.